# Text starting position Left, Center and Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I'm loading this animation, the text is starting from Left side of the HTML page.

But I need it like the below

> 1. "Hello" Should start from little outside of Left Top corner side of the html page
> 2. "Your" should start from little outside Middle Top (center top) of the page
> 3. "World" should start from little outside Right Top Corner of the page

(I have edited the above for better clarity and understanding)

All together, should come to the center zooming in. And all of them have to return zooming out to the left side of the page.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbLqbqfw/5/)

```js
$('#hello').animate({
      zoom: '150%',
      left: window.innerWidth / 1
}, 3000, function() {
    // 4. Pause for 3 seconds
    $(this).delay(3000)
    // 6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner,
    // (logo position) 
    // 7. Fades out when reaching the logo 8. Logo appears
    .animate({
        zoom: '40%',
        left:0
    }, 3000, function() {
        $(this).find('span').fadeOut()
    })
});
```

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    zoom: 200%;
    transition: zoom 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
<h1>&nbsp;H<span>ello</span>&nbsp;Y<span>our</span>&nbsp;W<span>orld</span></h1>
```

Comment: I am still expecting if this is possible as smooth as i have mentioned in the code above ?? the below two answers looks great..can anyone suggest with the .animate() function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the animation you need is quite complex (slide in and zoom from different sides), perhaps create a custom one?

in the example below i utilize 2D transforms and the animation's `step` attribute. i put 2 long `<span>` in between the words to push them to the sides.

click on the red box to start the animation. if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

**ps: i left borders on the elements so you can see how they move**

```js
$(function() {
  FixMargins();

  $(".container").click(function() {
    var phWidth = $(".placeholder").width();
    var height = $(".container").height();
    containerHeight = $(".theText").height();
    var newTopMargin = (height - containerHeight) / 2;
    
    $(".theText").animate({
      transform: 2
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        var newscale = 1 + +now;
       $(this).css({
         'transform': "scale(" + newscale + "," + newscale + ")",
                   "opacity":-1 + now
                   });
        $(this).css("margin-top",-150 + (newTopMargin+150) / 2 * now);
        $(".placeholder").css({
          "width": phWidth - phWidth * now/2
        });
        FixMargins();
      },
      duration: 700
    }).promise().done(function() {
      $(this).delay(500);
      var textTop = $(".theText").css("margin-top").split('p')[0];
      var textLeft = $(".theText").css("margin-left").split('p')[0];
      $(this).animate({
        transform: 2
      }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
          console.log(textLeft - textLeft * now);
          var newscale = 3 - +now;
          $(this).css('transform', "scale(" + newscale + "," + newscale + ")");

          $(".theText").css("marginLeft", textLeft - textLeft / 2 * now);
          $(".theText").css("marginTop", textTop - textTop / 2 * now);
        },
        duration: 500
      }).promise().done(function() {
       
        $(this).find('span').css({
          "position":"absolute"
        }).animate({
          "width":0,
          "opacity":0
        });
      });
    });


  });
});

function FixMargins() {

  width = $(".container").width();
  containerWidth = $(".theText").width();
  leftMargin = (width - containerWidth) / 2;
  $(".theText").css("marginLeft", leftMargin);

}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.theText {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:-150px;
  opacity:0;
}
.placeholder {

  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <span class="theText">
        H<span>ello</span>
  <span class="placeholder"></span>
  Y<span>our</span>
  <span class="placeholder"></span>
  W<span>orld</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this helps me but is not that smooth.. and another mistake i have done in communicating is, the text "Your" should start from center. (this is my mistake), Actually i had to say like the below: 1. text "Hello" should start from Outside Left Top Corner of the page. 2. text "Your" should start from little outside the page top center (middle of the page but on the top) 3. Text "World" should start from outside the right top corner of the page..shall update the same in my question.. my bad..

Comment: Ohhh... that changes things! But easy still, just copy & paste the margin animations from the other words and add a top margin animation for the central word. Don't worry about the smoothness, i just wrote this thing fast, you can adjust the vars and customize the animation as you see fit. :)

Comment: @JohnFranky i have updated the example, i hope it helps :)

Comment: exactly like expected, thank you.. i made small changes with the duration..like 2000 and 3000 and works perfect.

Comment: is there a way we can run this on the page load ? using window.onload = function() ?

Comment: yes, simply remove the `$(function() {` part and the `$(".container").click(function() {` part (and their respective closing brackets as well), and wrap this entire code with the window load event handler. or, if you actually mean DOM ready and not page load (load means all async content like iframes and images are fully loaded, DOM ready means when all elements are created) then you can remove the click handler ` $(".container").click(function() {` and use  `$(function() {` which runs when DOM is ready.

Comment: Yes, the $(function() { on the top worked on the page load.. thumbs Up ;). When i run this in html on google chrome, i see the anitmation is almost very near to the bookmark bar on the top. The zoom has to be in the middle of the page..

Comment: @JohnFranky you can increase the `margin-top` to push the text further down from the top edge. :)

Answer (score 3):

I edit your code's. But in this codes you havent class zoom and other classes. this code work is based on font size.

** Html **

```
<div id="hello">
    <h1>H <span>ello</span></h1>
    <h1>Y <span>our</span></h1>
    <h1>W <span>orld</span></h1>
</div>
```

** Css **

```
#hello h1 {
    width: 33%;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

** Edited > Css **

```
#hello{
    -webkit-animation: myfirst linear 12s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst linear 12s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {padding:0}
    10%  {padding: 40vh 0}
    50%  {padding: 40vh 0}
    85%  {padding: 40vh 0}
    100% {padding: 0}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {padding:0}
    10%  {padding: 40vh 0}
    50%  {padding: 40vh 0}
    85%  {padding: 40vh 0}
    100% {padding: 0}
}
```

** Jquery **

```
window.onload = function() {

    var h1 = $('#hello h1');
    h1.animate({fontSize: '5em'}, 5000,

        function () {
            h1.delay(3000);

            h1.animate({'font-size': '1em'}, 2000,
                function () {
                    h1.children('span').fadeOut(1000);
                }
            );

        }
    );
};
```